# How to create dependent drop-down list in Alfresco process service form?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn, alfresco-webscripts

I have added some values in 2 drop-down lists through options. but they currently there is no any dependency.
i want to select second drop-down list values based on first drop-down value selection.

What will be the best approach to achieve this in Alfresco process service.

We are using alfresco process service 1.8 version.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this issue by javascript where you can get element of your drop-down and set your drop-downs according selected values etc.